# Finding if a given arrow in a drawing is u-v or v-u.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I'm having trouble trying to solve a problem I was given for my homework in Vector Calculus, and I was wondering if someone could help me out. Here is the problem in question:

> 1. Draw two vectors as arrows in the plane of the paper with their tails together. Label them u and v. Draw a third arrow extending between the head of u and the head of v. This arrow will either represent the vector **u - v** or **v - u**. Explain how you can decide which of these it is (**u - v** or **v - u**).

I have the drawing set up on my paper, but I don't really know where to go from there. If you don't know the direction of the third arrow that you have to draw between u and v, how do you solve this to determine whether this final arrow represents 'u - v' or 'v - u'? Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}$ if and only if $\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{u}$. Does that help?

Comment: "Draw a third arrow extending between the head of u and the head of v." This seems kind of ambiguous, does 'between A and B' mean 'from A to B' or 'from B to A'? One of these is u-v and the other is v-u. I think they want you to draw one of these at random, and then justify which one it ends up being

Comment: See the diagram [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction).